# Prevent long empty space in bottom of vuetify component in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js

Currently I have a project which built using laravel 8 and I use vuetify for its component. I learned from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaI9tV8GQFk). But, as we can see in minute [14.01](https://youtu.be/VaI9tV8GQFk?t=770) there is a long empty space in the bottom of primary button. How to prevent or fix it? I think its caused after adding the `v-app` tag, but if I don't add it the component will not be showed. So, what I can do to fix it?
The example code and the result are below.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn
      depressed
      color="primary">
      Primary
    </v-btn>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

[image: example-image]

Comment: IMHO, it doesn't seem good to invite us to watch a video. This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The v-app is required for your Vuetify application to work. It fills the entire page and propagates your color theme to all child components. If you want to remove the extra space, you will have to overwrite min-height of the .v-application__wrap class.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/